# Position: absolute is not positioning to the nearest parent ancestor with a position of a different value than static successfully?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a restaurant menu. I need menu titles in the top right of my three paragraphs. I have set box-sizing to the value of border-box and floated the paragraphs to stay on one line. The paragraphs are responsive to 992px or greater so far. However, the menu titles(headings) are not responsive to the position of the paragraphs. I have floated them to the top-right corner for a 992px screen with the position: absolute. The paragraphs and menu titles are all under the id: container set to the position: relative. However, the menu title is moving farther left from the top-right corner as I resize the browser.

I've already set the items to position: absolute in CSS. I've set the paragraphs and menu titles under the id: container to relative. I'm using media queries.

This is the link to my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/0cufrjw6/

```
Main problem:
    #container{
        position: relative;
    }

    @media (min-width: 992px) {

        p {
            width: calc(33.33% - 40px) ;
            float: left;
        }   

        .item1{
            position: absolute; 
            left: 23.5%;
        }

        .item2{
            position: absolute;
            left: 60.25%
        }

        .item3{
            position: absolute;
            left: 92.25%
        }
          }
```

Comment: Is this the behaviour you were looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/5fr6gx3L/5/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Azer, this is the behavior I was looking for. This similar to what I did. However, you used the idea of a grid instead of width: calc(33.33% - 40px). What does this change? The most obvious change was each item under the class .item{}  is now positioned relative to the closest div with the class .menu-item{}. This is what I was trying to achieve with my code. Was the problem that the whole grid was positioned with the value: relative? Should each div contained in <div id=container> be read to be positioned relative to its nearest parent aka div elements with class .menu-item{}?

Comment: Paulie_D, thanks. I will check out LearnLayout.com. I do have a code snippet below my link. I understand that people like Azer just ended up changing my code on jsfiddle. This code might not be applicable for every web application having the same problem. However, would the same problem not exist if a snippet of that code was pasted here? The only other solution I see is the user not asking such a specific problem in his/her code. Would this not be less helpful to the user even if it might be more helpful to the community?